# query Springboot rest api response using graphql

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

is it possible to query Json which is a Rest endpoint response and filterout the required fields?
Sample Json response from springboot rest endpoint  -> api/getProductDetails as below,

```
{
  "account": "JV-013",
  "productDetails": [
    {
      "productId": 1,
      "productName": "birew",
      "productVersion": [
        "v1.0",
        "v2.0"
      ],
      "productOwner": [
        {
          "ownerName": "John",
          "ownerMail": "john34@yahoo.com"
        },
        {
          "ownerName": "Pav",
          "ownerMail": "pavghig@yahoo.com"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "productId": 1,
      "productName": "rowa",
      "productVersion": [
        "v1.0",
        "v2.0"
      ],
      "productOwner": [
        {
          "ownerName": "John",
          "ownerMail": "john34@yahoo.com"
        },
        {
          "ownerName": "Rias",
          "ownerMail": "rias765@yahoo.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

with using another rest endpoint or modifying the existing endponit want to filter out the response using graphql, for example if i want only the productOwner with OwnerName field alone details for all products/singleProduct my response should be below

```
{
  "productDetails": [
    {
      "productId": 1,
      "productOwner": [
        {
          "ownerName": "John"
        },
        {
          "ownerName": "Pav"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "productId": 1,
      "productOwner": [
        {
          "ownerName": "John"
        },
        {
          "ownerName": "Rias"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone please help with this

I tried with graphql endpoint. but Using springboot rest endponit is it possible to implement

Answer (score 0):

Only GraphQL will allow clients to completely drive which fields will be present in the response.

With a typical Spring MVC application, you can use [JSON Views](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-jsonview) to serialize your object in different ways. Now unlike GraphQL, the client will not be able to select the response content with a request DSL. You can select the JSON view by using different Controller methods:

- by changing the request path
- requiring request parameters
- using a different, custom media type like `application/vnd.product.light+json`, `application/vnd.product+json`

Comment: Thanks @Brian . I want to filter the response using fieldnames dynamically using one single controller in java Springboot
api/?fields=account,productDetails.productId,productdetails.productOwner.ownerName should return mentioned fields for all the available objects.